Python: detecting a letter pattern without iterating through all possible combinations
Apologies for the possibly not-very-useful title; I couldn't figure out how to summarise this problem into one sentence.
I'm trying to count how many "units" long a word is in Python 3.10. One "unit" is (C for consonant and V for vowel) either CV or VC or C or V (the latter two only being used when no pair can be made). For example, "piece" would be three units (pi-e-ce or pi-ec-e), "queue" would be four units (qu-e-u-e), and "lampshade" would be six units (la-m-p-s-ha-de).
What I'm struggling with is how exactly I would detect these units without iterating through every combination of every vowel and consonant for each pair of letters. It'd be hugely inefficient to do this with iteration, but I can't think of anything better with my current knowledge of Python. What would be an efficient way of solving this problem?
As an extra (optional) problem, what if digraphs are introduced, like "gh" and "th"? This would make words like "thigh" (four units, t-hi-g-h) into only two units (thi-gh), but also complicates the working-out.

Why would you have to iterate through every combination? Why not just check if one is a vowel and the other is a consonant?

Do you want to find ANY result, or a specific result. For example, asian should return as-i-an or a-si-an?

@RodrigoRodrigues - it seems to be more about finding "units", and in your example, either way is 3 units.

in that case, is as straightforward as counting how many times you change from a vowel to consonant or vice-versa. Just iterate once, no combinations required

@RodrigoRodrigues - you can't just count transitions because 'CV' and 'VC' are a unit. Example 'CVVVC' in your count is 2 but real count is 3. My answer illustrates 1 way to get the proper count. I could make it more direct, but I opted to make it easy to understand.

Just convert everything to 'V' or 'C', respectively, in a list. Then check the first 2 letters in a loop. If it's 'CV' or 'VC' pop the list, and no matter what, pop it again. Count the iterations it takes to exhaust the list.
def units(word) -> int:
    word = ["V" if c in "aeiou" else "C" for c in word]
    cnt = 0

    while word:
        if ''.join(word[:2]) in ('CV', 'VC'):
            word.pop(0)
        word.pop(0)
        cnt += 1
          
    return cnt
      
      
for word in ('queue', 'piece', 'lampshade'):
    print(word, units(word))


Does the c in if c in "aeiou" essentially mean it goes through word and changes each letter to V if it's somewhere in aeiou? (Sorry if this is a weird/basic question, the in keyword is something I've only used once, and it was for something a lot simpler than this program! Want to make sure I understand how this works)

Also: is there a way this can be adapted to deal with digraphs too, or would that be better suited for a different type of solution?

@Suntooth - the list comprehension iterates over every letter of the word storing them asCor V. For digraphs you need a second system. This handles types of characters. Digraphs are combinations of characters. Your digraph system could borrow from this system, though.

It could be done in multiple ways, but as I like functional programming style, here is one possible solution:
cv = lambda s: 'v' if s in 'aeiou' else 'c'

def units(cvs):
    match tuple(cvs):
        case c, v, *cvs if cv(c) != cv(v): return c+v, *units(cvs)
        case c, v, *cvs: return c, *units((v, *cvs))
        case _: return cvs
    
units('piece')      # ('pi', 'ec', 'e')
units('queue')      # ('qu', 'e', 'u', 'e')
units('lampshade')  # ('la', 'm', 'p', 's', 'ha', 'de')


Using regex:
import re

def units(word) -> int:
    v = '[aeiou]'
    c = '[^aeiou]'
    return len(re.findall(f'{v}{c}?|{c}{v}?', word))

for word in 'queue', 'piece', 'lampshade':
    print(word, units(word))

Or remembering which kind we get for free:
def units(word) -> int:
    count = 0
    free = None
    for char in word:
        kind = char in 'aeiou'
        if kind is free:
            free = None
        else:
            count += 1
            free = not kind
    return count

for word in 'queue', 'piece', 'lampshade':
    print(word, units(word))

Attempt This Online!
